# Angular Material: Table doesn't contain content

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm currently working on a little Angular project which is based on the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial. However, "hero/heroes" is replaced by "customer/customers" but everything is the same programming-wise.

So I've got this template:

```
<!-- This part isn't working. -->
<table #table mat-table [dataSource]="customers" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer"> {{customer.id}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="surname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Surname </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer"> {{customer.surname}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</table>

<!-- This part works - based on Tour of Heroes -->
<h2>Customers</h2>
<ul class="customers">
  <li *ngFor="let customer of customers">
    <a routerLink="/detail/{{customer.id}}">
      <span class="badge">{{customer.id}}</span> {{customer.surname}} {{customer.lastname}}
</a>
<button class="delete" title="delete customer" (click)="delete(customer)">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the component to the template:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from '../models/customer';
import { CustomerService } from '../customer.service';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers.component.css']
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {

  customers: Customer[];
  columnsToDisplay: ['ID', 'Surname'];

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCustomers();
  }

  getCustomers(): void {
    this.customerService.getCustomers().subscribe(customers => this.customers = customers);
  }

  delete(customer: Customer): void {
    this.customers = this.customers.filter(c => c !== customer);
    this.customerService.deleteCustomer(customer).subscribe();
  }
}
```

The Chrome console doesn't spit out any errors. I also imported the MatTableModule in the app.module.ts file.

My problem is similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141072/angular-material-data-table-no-data) but I don't even get the headlines and the solution didn't help here.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: is getCustomers() getting called onInit ? is your .subscribe() method executing?

Comment: Yes, getCustomers() is called in ngOnInit() method. The .subscribe() method is also being executed, the normal list (underneath the material table) lists all items which depends on this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your definition of `columnsToDisplay` (ID, Surname) does not match the columns defined in the template by `matColumnDef` (position, surname) therefore Angular cannot find/display them.

Either change in `ts`:

```
columnsToDisplay = ['position', 'surname'];
```

or in `HTML`:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="ID">...</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="Surname">...</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is columnsToDisplay is does not match. And you have to update the datasource.

Here is my answer.

In your .html,

```
<table #table mat-table [dataSource]="customerDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer">{{customer.id}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="surname">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Surname</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer">{{customer.surName}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</table>

<h2>Customers</h2>
<ul class="customers">
  <li *ngFor="let customer of customers">
    <a routerLink="/detail/{{customer.id}}">
      <span class="badge">{{customer.id}}</span> {{customer.surName}} {{customer.lastName}}
</a>
<button class="delete" title="delete customer" (click)="delete(customer)">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your .ts,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from '../models/customer';
import { CustomerService } from '../customer.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers.component.css']
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {

  customers: Customer[] = [];
  columnsToDisplay: ['position', 'surname'];
  customerDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.customers);

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCustomers();
  }

  getCustomers(): void {
    this.customerService.getCustomers().subscribe(customers => {
        this.customers = customers;
        this.customerDataSource.data = this.customers;
    });
  }

  delete(customer: Customer): void {
    this.customers = this.customers.filter(c => c !== customer);
    this.customerService.deleteCustomer(customer).subscribe();
  }
}
```

In customer.model.ts class,

```
export class Customer{
    id: number;
    surName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped at least for one further step. Now the table has as many rows as the number of customers. However, each row is only rendered with a comment in it, see my screenshot: [link](https://cdn3.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/10/7/d08b21a399bdecf406b157fb48b9f7e6-full.png)

Comment: @KiraTM how do you add customers to table?

Comment: @KiraTM I guess there are duplicate customers in the table.

Comment: The customers are stored in a in-memory-data.ts file (just as in the Tour of Heroes tutorial). Then, then customerSevice.getCustomers() method fetches all entries from there and gives them back as an Observable<Customer[]> which is then written into customers in the component's ts file.

Comment: @KiraTM are there duplicate customers in the table?

Comment: @KiraTM make sure to import MatTableDataSource. I edited my answer check on that.